# How to serialize object that has closures inside properties?

Tags: php, string, serialization, closures

if I do `serialize($obj)`, I get:

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Is there any way these closures can be ignored when serializing? I don't need them when I unserialize the string anyway (value of those properties can be null or whatever).

My class looks smth like this:

```
Class Node{

  protected $attrs = array();

}
```

`$attrs` is an associative array that can contain some elements that are closures, like
`$attrs['validator'] = function(){...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a function that allows any `Exception` to be serialized. This is done by flattening complex values in the backtrace.

#### Source:

https://gist.github.com/Thinkscape/805ba8b91cdce6bcaf7c

#### Usage:

```
<?php
try {
    // exception gets thrown here, i.e.
    // throw new Exception(); 
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    flattenExceptionBacktrace($exception);
    $serialized = serialize($exception);

    $unserialized = unserialize($serialized);
    print_r($unserialized->getTraceAsString());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It's simple: You can't. A closure is not serializable. If you want to create "something similar", you can use objects of a class implementing [`__invoke()`](http://php.net/oop5.magic#object.invoke) instead of the closures.

If you don't need the closures (or you can recreate them yourself while unserializing) you can implement [`Serializable`](http://php.net/serializable) and don't take the closures into account while serializing. This interface (implementing `serialize()` and `unserialize()`) should be prefered over `__sleep()`/`__wakeup()`.

Answer (score 2):

provide your own implementation of [_*sleep()*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) and [_wakeup](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) methods

Comment: so in the __sleep method I remove the elements that are closures from my array property?

Answer (score 1):

To serialize properties of an object while ignoring closures :

```
$properties = array_map(function ($property) {
    try {
        return serialize($property);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}, get_object_vars($this));
```