# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: php, exception, closures, amqp

I have a custom Exception handler in my code (which used to work properly), until suddenly I saw this error yesterday:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed' in /raid0/nginx/www/voiceportal/lib/logutils.php:34 Stack trace:
#0 /raid0/nginx/www/voiceportal/lib/logutils.php(34): serialize(Array)
#1 [internal function]: custom_exception_handler(Object(AMQPConnectionException))
#2 {main}
```

I read that it can be caused if an anonymous function is tried to be serialized, but this is what threw the error for me:

```
//logutils.php
function custom_exception_handler($exception) {
   $trace_id = uniqid();
   $trace = serialize(array('trace_id' => $trace_id, 'trace' => $exception->getTrace()));
   ...
}
```

Not sure if it was caused by trying to serialize getTrace(), but if I remember correctly, it used to work earlier.

The original exception was (as seen in the trace) `AMQPConnectionException`.

I am trying to understand what caused the `'Serialization of Closure not allowed'` exception.

Thanks!

Comment: What is returning value of `$exception->getTrace()`?

Comment: I don't know what exception occurred in the main code, so don't know that.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You have to provide more details

Comment: So the original exception was an AMQPConnectionException. More details added to the question.

Comment: You have to show full body of `custom_exception_handler` as well as the code catching this exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP's backtrace structure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) includes a reference to the object whose method is being called at each level of the stack. When it tries to serialize the trace, any objects which reference closures (or reference objects which themselves reference closures and so on) will prevent serialization.

In your case, you can re-cast the trace into a slightly less descriptive form or find which objects contain closures and either repackage the closures as `__invoke` instances or skip them when serializing by implementing `Serializable`, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14235869/745831). Your choice here would depend on what you're doing with the trace. If it's only meant to a be human-readable description of what went wrong, consider using the `getTraceAsString()` method instead of `getTrace()`.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a function that allows any `Exception` to be serialized. This is done by flattening complex values in the backtrace.

#### Source:

https://gist.github.com/Thinkscape/805ba8b91cdce6bcaf7c

#### Usage:

```
//logutils.php
function custom_exception_handler($exception) {
   flattenExceptionBacktrace($exception); // <---- ADD THIS
   $trace_id = uniqid();
   $trace = serialize(array('trace_id' => $trace_id, 'trace' => $exception->getTrace()));
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old topic, but I would like to recommend my own [library to serializing stack traces](https://github.com/awesomite/stack-trace). Object $stackTrace can contain values and can be serialized. Unserialized object will contain only custom dumps of variables ([@see interface](https://github.com/awesomite/stack-trace/blob/master/src/Arguments/Values/ValueInterface.php)).